# How to store data from a Google Chrome Extension to an external server?

Tags: javascript, php, google-chrome-extension

I'm new here (new account but have been using this site to fix problems for a while), and I have a quick question about how I want to collect and then store data from a **Google Chrome Extension** in an external server.
I have an external server already set up and have begun the process of developing my extension.
I want to know if it is possible (or even the best way) to collect the data by first storing it all in `localstorage` and then at the end of the session send all the data collected to an external server.
It is for an academic project so it will all be securely stored and the user will be aware of all the data that will be collect and stored.

In short: Can I store data collected in `localstorage` then send this to an external server at the end of a session?

Thank you in advance

Comment: You should make some api and send data from extension via ajax request to your api with content of localstorage in request body

Comment: Thanks, managed to sort it!

Comment: If somebody is looking to send just text, look: https://paste.scratchbook.ch/api